# Need Excel Formula to Duplicate Cell Value Based on Another Column's Count

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, salesforce

Preparing a spreadsheet for a Data Insert.

I'm trying to create child records for a parent.

I have a spreadsheet where there are two main columns e.g count of child Records(column a) and the ParentID(column B). If the count of Child Records is equal to 7. I need a formula to paste the Parent ID down 7 Rows.

Overall I need to create 659 Child Records. The Maximum number of child records I need to create for a Parent is 7. Of course these can be done manually but I want an efficient solution or a less cumbersome one at that.

Context: Trying to be a more efficient SF Admin.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @music2myear, in the end - I filtered and grouped rows according to their Parent Record Count. When I filtered for records where the parent record count was 7 i copied the selection and pasted it down 7 times. I did this for rows where  Parent record count was 6,5,4,3.. In summary I achieved my goal and I was able to prepare the spreadsheet for update.

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In The End

For each set of child records, I filtered them based on their count. For instance, if a parent record had 7 child records, I filtered out these 7 records, copied them, and then pasted this selection 7 times. This step was repeated for each different child record count.

After completing the above, I organised the data by sorting the 'Parent Record ID' column in ascending order. This helped in grouping the rows according to their respective parent records.

Finally, I created a formula that generated a unique identifier for each child record names, tailored to the specific requirements we had at the time.

This last step was crucial for inserting the records into our system

For any questions, please reach out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1st record is located at A2 and B2. Try put this in C2 cell :

```
=IF(B2="",C1,B2)
```

Then drag the cell downwards.

Idea :
Check if left cell is blank. If not, take its value. If yes, take the value from the cell above the current one.

Please share if it works/not.